# Another Hard Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, problem-solving, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find the minimum of

$$\frac{y^2+1}{x^2+z+1}+\frac{x^2+1}{y+z^2+1}+\frac{z^2+1}{x+y^2+1}$$

with $x,y,z>-1$.

The answer is 2, when $x=y=z=1$.

I am stuck.  Here is what I have so far:

$$\frac{y^2+1}{x^2+z+1}+\frac{x^2+1}{y+z^2+1}+\frac{z^2+1}{x+y^2+
   1}=3-\left(\frac{x^2-y^2+z}{x^2+z+1}+\frac{-x^2+y+z^2}{y+z^2+1}+\frac{x+y^2-
   z^2}{x+y^2+1}\right)\geq 3-\left(\frac{x^2-y^2+z}{2
   x+z}+\frac{-x^2+y+z^2}{y+2 z}+\frac{x+y^2-z^2}{x+2
   y}\right)=-\left(\frac{x^2-y^2+z}{2 x+z}+\frac{-x^2+y+z^2}{y+2
   z}+\frac{x+y^2-z^2}{x+2 y}\right)+2+1=\left(\frac{(x-y)
   \left(x^2-y^2+z\right)}{(2 x+z) (x+y+z)}+\frac{(x-z)
   \left(x^2-y-z^2\right)}{(y+2 z) (x+y+z)}+\frac{(y-z)
   \left(x+y^2-z^2\right)}{(x+2 y) (x+y+z)}\right)+2$$

Source: https://brilliant.org/problems/minimum-11/?ref_id=1411033
(I did not write this question)

Answer (score 1):

For $x=y=z=1$ we'll get a value $2$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2+1}{x^2+z+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(y^2+1)^2}{(y^2+1)(x^2+z+1)}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+1)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+1)(x^2+z+1)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+1)\right)^2\geq2\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+1)(x^2+z+1)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2y-2x)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}((x^2-y)^2+(x-1)^2)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Why is $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2+1}{x^2+z+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(y^2+1)^2}{(x^2+z+1)^2}$$ ?

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut It was typo. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Nice answer!